# Count by unique values in other fields in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this:

```
Year    Month   Type
2013    4   31
2013    3   31
2014    5   40
2014    6   41
2015    5   31
2015    7   40
2013    4   31
2013    3   31
2014    5   40
2014    6   41
2015    5   31
2015    7   40
2013    4   31
2013    3   31
```

I would like to count number of appearance of each combination. So output should be something like this:

```
Year    Month   Type    Count_of_appearance
2013    3   31  3
2013    4   31  3
etc..
```

I've been using something like:

```
SELECT Year,
       Month,
       Type,
       (SELECT COUNT (*)
          FROM myTable
         WHERE (...im lost in defining a condition in order to make this work...)
           AS Count_of_appearance
  FROM employee;
```

I'm lost at defining functional WHERE clause.

Problem is I a have a lot of fields like this and a lot of unique values. Table is 8Gb big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Year, Month, Type, COUNT(*) AS Count_of_appearance
FROM employee
GROUP BY Year, Month, Type
ORDER BY Year, Month, Type;
```

To ensure that the results are in the right order, you should include an `ORDER BY` as well.